# C++ Array, average value (Beginner)

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2013, pseudocode

I need some help creating an array with 10 number that the user can pick. Had a post about this yesterday but misstook arrays for vectors..

Need to calculate the average value of the numbers, need pseudocode for it as well.
Any help would be awesome, I do have a school book but the array examples in it will just not work (as you can se in the code I'll add).

This is what I got sofar:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int n[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter number " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> n[i];
    }



    float average(int v[], int n)
    {
        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sum += v[i]; //sum all the numbers in the vector v
        }

        return sum / n;
    }
system("pause");
}
```

the part to calculate the average I got help with from the last post I had. But everything else won't work "/ So basicly I need help to make a array with 10 user input numbers. Cheers

Comment: Where are you asking for user input?

Comment: Why are you creating an array? Why not calculate the average as you get inputs?

Comment: The code above will not compile.

Comment: I would love to see the book which has such example codes

Comment: There, now I'm asking for user input?
Gett error "error C2601: 'average' : local function definitions are illegal" though "/ This is my second week trying to learn programming. I do not have much knowledge to work with.

Comment: @Nyp0ns0pp0saurus Try defining function `average` above `main()`.

Comment: Yep- one big thing in programming is to try to figure out what the error codes mean.  Not trying to be a jerk- it really is a valuable skill which will help clear up these headaches.  The error message is pretty clear; even if you don't understand what a local function definition is, you know there's something wrong with average.  If you moved it to after the main block, it still wouldn't compile- you'd need a function declaration above main because C/C++ can't generally look ahead in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that you wrote correctly is function average. I would add qualifier const to the parameter of the function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

float average( const int v[], int n )
{
    float sum = 0.0f;

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        sum += v[i]; //sum all the numbers in the vector v
    }

    return sum / n;
}
```

Or statmenet

```
return sum / n;
```

could be substituted for

```
return ( n == 0 ? 0.0f : sum / n );
```

Take into account that functions shall be defined outside any other functions and a function declaration shall appear before usage of the function.

You need not header `<array>` because it is not used. But you need to include header `<cstdlib>` because you use function `system`.

As it is written in your assigment you need enter arbitrary values for the array

```
int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    int a[N];

    cout << "Enter " << N << " integer values: ";
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) cin >> a[i];

    cout << "Average of the numbers is equal to " << average( a, N ) << endl;

    system( "pause" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! I did not get that I needed to put the average calculation outside main until I saw your answer, care to give me some tips and pointers in how to make good pseudocode for this? need to make a diagram of some sort, don't know the work in English but roughly activity-diagram. You rock dude! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

1. Function definition should always be outside main.
2. `int n[10]` mean `n` is array of integers of size `10`. They are not array of pointers of type `char *` to hold strings
3. There isn't a caller for function `average`. Subroutines work like, callers will call callee passing arguments to perform operations on them and return them back - pass by reference.

Comment: So int n[10]; does not make a array with 10 elements?

Comment: @Nyp0ns0pp0saurus Yes it makes.

Comment: So the code I'v replaced will give the user the ability to pick 10 numbers that will be those 10 elements?

Answer (score 1):

`int n[10];` - `n` is an array of `int`s, not strings, so why are you doing `n[0] = "Number 1: ";`? You should instead loop and ask for an input from the user.

After you do this, you should place `average` function *outsude* the `main` function and call it from the `main`.

I advise you to go through a [basic tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/).

Comment: Cause My book use the example "temp[5]; and temp[0] = .. and so on "/